# AngularJS - Load content in tab through controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use `ng-repeat` and a controller to dynamically load tab content.

Controller code:

```
angular.module('ogn.userprefs').controller('UserprefsController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.tabs = [
            { title: 'Personal Information', content: "ng-include=''modules/userprefs/views/personalinfo.html''"},
            { title: 'Sign In & Security', content: 'modules/userprefs/views/signin_security.html'},
            { title: 'Account Preferences', content: 'modules/userprefs/views/accountprefs.html'}
        ];
}]);
```

HTML code:

```
<div ng-show="subnav" class="userprefs">
  <div ng-controller="UserprefsController" class="subnav-tabs">
    <!--<tabset>
      <tab heading="Personal Information">
        <div ng-include="'modules/userprefs/views/personalinfo.html'"></div>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Sign In &amp; Security">
        <div ng-include="'modules/userprefs/views/signin_security.html'"></div>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Account Preferences">
        <div ng-include="'modules/userprefs/views/accountprefs.html'"></div>
      </tab>
    </tabset>-->
    <tabset>
      <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
        {{tab.content}}
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML code that has been commented out is how I called the content in my tab before, using `hg-include`. I want to switch to an `ng-repeat` and call it through the controller, but all that is coming up is text that follows `content:`. What can I replace after `content` to call my html pages?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you are getting the HTML, but encoded/escaped?

Comment: @Meligy so the original code (commented out) uses ng-include to call my HTML pages, but when I try to call the same URL in the controller, it just comes back as text and not the page in that tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `<ng-include>` directive and set the `src` attribute to your scope variable. Something like this:

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="{{tab.active}}">
    <ng-include src="tab.content"></ng-include>
</tab>
```

Here's a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j95pfoa2/1/) demonstrating the usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('ogn.userprefs').controller('UserprefsController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.tabs = [
            { title: 'Personal Information', content: 'personalinfo.html'},
            { title: 'Sign In & Security', content: 'signin_security.html'},
            { title: 'Account Preferences', content: 'accountprefs.html'}
        ];
}]);


<div ng-show="subnav" class="userprefs">
  <div ng-controller="UserprefsController" class="subnav-tabs">
    <tabset>
      <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
        <div ng-include="modules/userprefs/views/{{tab.content}}"></div>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should work, but [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vtkhBeVFNJL3h7sCk4VJ?p=preview) is a little plunker i prepared with example. I guess that first index in tabs scope is messing around with double `''`. Remember to download and include ui.bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You should really try and either preload these templates or use custom directives as using `<ng-include>` creates an unnecessary watch.  Also consider using one-time binding syntax for your tab array if you don't expect it to change.